# Blending different images in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas, which i draw many different PNGs images - for the example we use this image [image]

I want to draw each PNG with a different blend color using multiply blend and affect only on the area the image is drawn - on the bomb and not on the bounding rect of the image.

This is my wanted result

[image]

I tried doing this by performing this code

```
context.drawImage(image, drawLocSize[0], drawLocSize[1], drawLocSize[2],     drawLocSize[3]);

context.fillStyle = wantedColor;
context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
context.fillRect(drawLocSize[0], drawLocSize[1], drawLocSize[2], drawLocSize[3]);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

and as expected i got this result.

[image]

Tried also to draw the image instead of `fillrect`, but didn't work as well.

The question is how do I do that only on the image area and not on the image rectangle.
and also in this way when the bombs will be one on each other the result will be that the lower bomb will be composite by it's color and by the upper bomb color. which is not good for me.

I don't want to reprocess each image before due to allot of images, different colors, and many changes in the draw.

I'm doing the same in WebGL, simply multiply my fragment color in the blend color in my fragment shader. I want to do the same in Context2D.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do the images have a transparent background ?

Comment: Yes as show above (the transparent is the white/gray checkers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution for doing this. But it is with 2 drawing phases.

First an filled rectangle on top of the image in temporary canvas (using 'source-atop' composite), and then multiply it on the main canvas.

First i'm creating a canvas and getting it's context once.

```
this._tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
this._tmpCtx = this._tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
```

then in my drawing cycle i'm doing this

```
ctx.drawImage(currPtData.image, drawLocSize[0], drawLocSize[1], drawLocSize[2], drawLocSize[3]);

this._tmpCanvas.width = drawLocSize[2];
this._tmpCanvas.height = drawLocSize[3];

this._tmpCtx.drawImage(currPtData.image, 0, 0, drawLocSize[2], drawLocSize[3]);
this._tmpCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
this._tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'red';
this._tmpCtx.fillRect(0, 0, drawLocSize[2], drawLocSize[3]);
```

The temp canvas look like this now [image] - (It saves the transparency as well). And now we multiplying this canvas in our main context.

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
ctx.drawImage(this._tmpCanvas, drawLocSize[0], drawLocSize[1], drawLocSize[2], drawLocSize[3]);
// setting the composite back
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

And the result look like this[image].

But i'm still open for better performances solutions if there are.